# Validation Condition In Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Hello I'm trying to submit data as per type. There 2 types 1.Answer 2.Sub Flow. But my save button not enabled when I'm selecting sub flow. Please help me What I'm missing there.

BELOW IS THE HTML FILE CODE

```
<div class="row">
```

```
<div class="box">
  <app-question-error *ngIf="isError" [errorData]='errorData'></app-question-error>

  <form *ngIf="!isError" [formGroup]="questionForm" (ngSubmit)="SubmitForm()">
     <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Type </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-between">

              <select formControlName="subflow" class="form-control" (change)="onDropDownChange($event)">
                <option>Answer</option>
                <option>Subflow</option>
              </select>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div *ngIf="subflowSelection == 'Subflow'">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <ng-select [items]="flowNames" bindLabel="flowName" appendTo="body" multiple="true"
                  formControlName="subflow">
                </ng-select>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ng-container *ngIf="subflowSelection === 'Answer'">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-sm-12" formArrayName="answers">
          <div *ngFor="let quantity of getAnswers().controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{mylabels.answer}} </label>
              <div class="col-sm-9 d-flex justify-content-between">
                <input type="text" class="form-control w-90" formControlName="answerText">
                <span class="mr-2"></span>

                <button (click)="removeAnswers(i)">
                  <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-9 has-error" *ngIf="f.answers.touched && !f.answers.valid">
            {{mylabels.answerRequired}}
          </div>
          <div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> </label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <div class="add-more-answers ">
                <button type="button" (click)="addAnswers()"
                  class="col-12 col-md-5 col-sm-12 btn btn-blue">{{mylabels.add_more_ans}}</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
         <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row d-flex justify-content-end">
            <button [routerLink]="['/question-list']" type="button"
              class="btn btn-gray btn-sm mr-4">{{mylabels.cancel}}</button>
            <button type="submit" [disabled]="!questionForm.valid"
              class="btn btn-red btn-sm  ">{{mylabels.save}}</button>
          </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
  </form>
```

Below is TS file code Where I'm creating form controls.

```
  this.questionForm = this.fb.group({
  questionText: ['', Validators.required],
  questionHelp: '',
  questionNote: '',
  remarks:'',
  multiAns: [false],
  answers: this.fb.array([]),
  subflow:'',
});
}
```

Above file is for Answer and Sub flow Drop down. Can anyone here who can help me for solving this issue. below is the screenshot for that save button.

**1.Diabled Save Button after selecting sub flow option**
[image]

**2.Enabled Save Button after selecting Answer Option**

[image]

Comment: Can you also post the code where you're creating the form controls, please

Comment: We need your typescript code, but you probably have validators on the answer fields. You can disable the answer field from the form when the selected type is subflow, this way the validator will not run and the form will be valid.

Comment: Hi @DanielGrabowski can you please help me here how I can disable that "answer" div when "subflow" option is selected.

Comment: Hi @Batajus  `  this.questionForm = this.fb.group({
      questionText: ['', Validators.required],
      questionHelp: '',
      questionNote: '',
      remarks:'',
      multiAns: [false],
      answers: this.fb.array([]),
      subflow:'',
    });
  } `  This is my Form control creating code

Comment: We also need the code where you add the answers, without it, this is just a guess. I think you have a validator for each answer. To help you understand this better, you need to check the value of questionForm.controls, one of the controls is going to have the status invalid and that makes the whole questionForm invalid. If there is a validator, you need to create an on change event for the type field, when its value is subflow, disable the answers field with the command this.questionForm.get('answers').disable();. Documentation: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable

Comment: @DanielGrabowski Thank you for your solution It's worked for me.  I did this.questionForm.get('answers').disable();. when dropdown type = SubFlow